# Why doesn't httpx ssl context set cipher

Tags: python, http, ssl, encryption, httpx

```
ctx = httpx.create_ssl_context()
ctx.set_ciphers("TLS_AES_128_GCM_SHA256:TLS_CHACHA20_POLY1305_SHA256:TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256:TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256:TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384:TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384:TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_CHACHA20_POLY1305_SHA256:TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_CHACHA20_POLY1305_SHA256:TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA:TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA:TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256:TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384:TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA:TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA")
```

That are the cipher suites I've got from my http debugger, but after running this it says

```
ssl.SSLError: ('No cipher can be selected.',)
```

I didn't even make a request so I think it's unsupported?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You need to ensure that every single cipher name there use OpenSSL's naming for the ciphers.

There's a possibility one or more of the ciphers you used there are the "public" names, but OpenSSL has their own names for those ciphers.

Take a look at this for the mapping:

https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.1.1/man1/ciphers.html